# Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a form using Material UI's autocomplete feature. The field renders chips however I am unable to modify the onDelete prop of the chip component. I have tried modifying other props such as the variant, label, etc but even trying to get the onDelete prop to do a simple console log does not work. My code is below.

```
        <Autocomplete
      onChange={handleRecChange("foodRecs")}
      multiple
      options={menuItems}
      renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
        value.map((option, index) => (
          <Chip
            variant="outlined"
            key={option}
            label={option}
            onDelete={() => console.log("test")}
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
          />
        ))
      }
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          label="Recommendations"
          placeholder="Choose anything from the menu"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: How are you capturing user selections? I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the actual selected values of the Autocomplete...

Answer (score 4):

That's because you override `onDelete` in this line:

```
{...getTagProps({ index })}
```

`getTagProps` is a getter for the tag props. It includes `onDelete` function, since `onDelete` is a `Chip` property (you can print the `getTagProps` return value to see that).

You should place`getTagProps` on the first line, to avoid unwanted prop overrides:

```
  <Chip
    {...getTagProps({ index })}
    variant="outlined"
    key={option}
    label={option}
    onDelete={() => console.log("test")}
  />
```